# using fmtlib to log but logging macro doesn't expose stream

Tags: c++, memory, formatting, fmt

## Preface

I have a LOG macro. In fact it's much more complicated and this is a simplified example.
`#define LOG(level) if (g_logLevel >= level) std::cout`
The macro itself cannot be changed and I don't want to create another macro just for fmt logging.

## Use cases

```
LOG(ERROR) << "We got an error"; // Original use cases
LOG(INFO) << "42"; 
LOG(INFO) << fmt::format("42 {}", "is the answer"); // Bad, std::string created...

fmt::print(LOG(INFO), "42 {}", "is the answer"); // Doesn't compile.

// Write an overload for `<<` of the data structure will work, but it's tedious to do it everytime just for a log line..
```

## Limitation

1. Cannot change the logging macro
2. Cannot define a new macro for it.
3. Fit *one-liner* use case `LOG(INFO) << myformat("42 {}", foo)`.

## Requirements

1. No dynamic memory allocation (within fixed size)
2. Thread safe without synchronization
3. Accept solutions for C++ 11 to C++ 20

## My attempt

Create a wrapper function for `fmt::format_to` and it returns `std::string_view` which wraps a thread local `fmt::memory_buffer`.

It doesn't dynamically allocate memory as long as buffer size < `SIZE`.

Is there a better approach? Is returning `fmt::memory_buffer` better than `thread_local`?

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3ovsPWbjG)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <atomic>
#include <string_view>

enum LogLevel{
    CRITICAL = 0,
    ERROR,
    WARN,
    INFO,
};

std::atomic<LogLevel> g_logLevel{ERROR};

#define LOG(level) if (g_logLevel >= level) std::cout

using fmt_membuf = fmt::basic_memory_buffer<char, 2048>;

template <typename... T>
std::string_view myFormat(fmt::format_string<T...>fmt, T&& ...args){
    thread_local fmt_membuf out;
    out.clear();
    fmt::format_to(std::back_inserter(out), fmt, args...);
    return std::string_view(out.data(), out.size());
}

int main()
{ 
    g_logLevel = WARN;
    LOG(ERROR) << myFormat("Expected logged\n");
    LOG(INFO) << myFormat("42 won't show\n");
    LOG(CRITICAL) << myFormat("CRITICAL!\n");
    // fmt::format_to(LOG(ERROR), "42"); // <-- cannot compile
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want efficient lazy evaluation you'll have to change the macro or introduce another one taking format arguments. For example, folly has [`XLOGF` and `FB_LOGF`](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/6b3dc22be2fd22057d0660e60be6dc7d7a63f1b4/folly/logging/docs/Usage.md?plain=1#L61) for this purpose.

A less efficient option is to capture arguments and the format string in some object and perform lazy formatting when it is streamed. This is less efficient because you have to copy arguments to prevent lifetime issues. You could use lambda for this as suggested in another answer but in addition to being less efficient it's also more cumbersome to use.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like there is no easy way without changing the macro.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve lazy evaluation by passing a lambda to your log function (no macro's required). And then only calling the lambda that does the string formatting if the log coniditions are met. E.g. like this :

```
#include <array>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <type_traits>

enum LogLevel 
{
    CRITICAL = 0,
    ERROR,
    WARN,
    INFO,
};

LogLevel g_logLevel{ WARN };

template <typename... args_t>
std::string_view myFormat(std::format_string<args_t...>fmt, args_t&&... args) {
    thread_local std::array<char, 2048> buffer; // tricky format_to has no size limit :(
    auto end = std::format_to(buffer.begin(), fmt, std::forward<args_t>(args)...);
    return std::string_view{ buffer.begin(), end };
}


// TODO find better way of injecting log_level
// globals are not that good a design (accross translation units)
LogLevel g_logLeve{ LogLevel::WARN };

template<typename fn_t>
auto log(const LogLevel level, fn_t fn) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<decltype(fn()), std::string_view>, void>
{
    if (level <= g_logLevel)
    {
        std::cout << fn();
    }
}

int main()
{
    int value{ 21 };
    log(LogLevel::INFO, [=] { return myFormat("42 won't show, it is {}\n", value); });
    log(LogLevel::WARN, [=] { return myFormat("Some {}\n", "warnig"); });
    log(LogLevel::ERROR, [=] { return myFormat("ERROR logged\n"); });
    log(LogLevel::CRITICAL, [=] { return myFormat("CRITICAL!\n"); });
    return 0;
}
```

This approach together with capturing data for formatting by value means it is also easy to move all the logging to a background thread if needed.

Comment: Sorry my title might be misleading. I want to persist the original `LOG(INFO) << "log texts"` syntax while utilizing `fmt`

Comment: Your suggestion is to use `std::array` instead but `fmt::memory_buffer` may specify size in it's second template argument. I believe `fmt::memory_buffer` is better than `std::array` especially when format size is larger than the fixed size..

Comment: @LouisGo Oh I forgot to mention that this was only to get my example compiling. I don't have the format library installed (only C++20). The same is true for array, I can specifiy its size too. But I could not quickly find how to limit format to honor that size

Comment: You can play with my example in godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/TjzooW7ET.  GodBolt doesn't have all fmt versions compiled on all compilers so trunk of `fmt` might not work in certain compilers.

Comment: I don't really have time to play around at the moment. And in general I don't like to have lines of logging inside my production code at all. I declare an abstract baseclass with methods like "virtual void ReportSomethingWentWrong(args...) = 0;" And inject that interface in my code.  Then during unit testing I can inject a mock that does nothing. And in production code I can inject a class that logs to the log system of the day (in the past eventlog, or text file, tomorrow an elastics server). Just some thought for when you are ready to refactor and change you log lines.

Comment: And unit testing will allow you to remove (a lot of) internal logging too, since you know code just works

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my domain I cannot access to gdb and live debug on my own. What I could count on is logging so I still want this approach to work.

Comment: Not being able to debug in live/production is common. There will always be need for logging, but if you have unit tested code you don't have to log things to validate the logic of your code (which will reduce the amount of logging). But sure there will be logging for things outside your control (user input, file system, security etc.. etc..). 
I just wanted to give you a nudge towards unit testing too ;)